# Does System.out.write method flush the stream?

Tags: java

```
public class Test {
 public static void main(String..args) {
    System.out.println("Testing.");
    System.out.print("Testing Again.");
    }
  }
```

Hello i'm new in java and i reading it from Herbert Schildt Book.
So my first Question.

1. I want to know in above program that does `print()` method flushes the stream As `println()` flushes after a newline at end.
2. Does `System.out.write();` Method flushes the stream?.
   Please be Specific.

Comment: Downvoters, now that this question is properly formatted, I do not see how this question is invalid? It pertains to streams and flushing. Care to comment why downvoted?

Comment: I did not downvote, but I'm pretty sure the twitch got them after seeing "pls help me learn language" instead of specifically asking about outputstream functions.

Comment: Great! Title is now a better reflection of your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, both `System.out.print` and `System.out.write` also flush the stream.

(**edit:** it seems the stream is only flushed if the input string contains a newline).

If you look at the source code for `PrintStream.java` from `java.io`, you can see the source:

```
private void write(char buf[]) {
    try {
        synchronized (this) {
            ensureOpen();
            textOut.write(buf);
            textOut.flushBuffer();
            charOut.flushBuffer();
            if (autoFlush) {
                for (int i = 0; i < buf.length; i++)
                    if (buf[i] == '\n')
                        out.flush();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (InterruptedIOException x) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
    catch (IOException x) {
        trouble = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: As far as I can tell, this answers the question, so why is it downvoted?

Comment: @maja I'm not sure, but the streams api is pretty low-level. best guess is that `checkError()` method is used some other place.

Comment: In my book program statement is like that.
char ch='A';
System.out.write(ch);
System.out.write('\n');
Now that i think it doesn't fit in to your explanation of write().

Comment: @user3545458 I think you're right - the underlying stream `out` only seems to be flushed if the string contains a newline.

Answer (score 1):

From [java docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println%28%29)

`Println()` Terminates the current line by writing the line separator string. The line separator string is defined by the system property line.separator, and is not necessarily a single newline character ('\n').

`println(String)` Prints a String and then terminate the line. This method behaves as though it invokes print(String) and then println().

`print()`
Prints an object. The string produced by the String.valueOf(Object) method is translated into bytes according to the platform's default character encoding, and these bytes are written in exactly the manner of the write(int) method.

and `write()`
Writes the specified byte to this stream. If the byte is a newline and automatic flushing is enabled then the flush method will be invoked.
Note that the byte is written as given; to write a character that will be translated according to the platform's default character encoding, use the print(char) or println(char) methods.

Edit:- Missed to add one imp line, `Optionally, a PrintStream can be created so as to flush automatically; this means that the flush method is automatically invoked after a byte array is written, one of the println methods is invoked, or a newline character or byte ('\n') is written.`

To create a printstream object with autoflush enabled `out = new PrintWriter(.getOutputStream(), true ) ;`